# shell change the sql insert value

Tags: shell

A sql dumped file contains the following statements, I would like to change the first column value and make it start from 1. The first column value is not necessarily continuous.

```
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('123', '2018-03-07 00:30:00', null);    
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('125', '2018-03-07 00:30:00', null);
```

Comment: If it is a db dump file, it would not be a good idea to make modifications like this in the dump file as there could be other lines that might get changed. The best option would be to restore the dump, delete the column that you want to modify, and add the column with `auto_increment` set

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut I am testing when the data is fully loaded, how poor the selection performance would be. In case I may have to have db sharding.

Comment: Can you provide the source and target of this operation. It is unclear what exactly you want to accomplish

Comment: @RomeoNinov In order to evaluate weather I should do database sharding, I need to evaluate the db size. One issue is my coworker gave me this dumpfile larger than any vim or cat could open. So I need to use command like awk and sed to change id value, so I could load it into db, without complaining "duplicate primary key“ because the sql file he gave contains duplicate ids.

Comment: @Tiina, provide in question the input and expected output